# Retrieve LastModifiedBy from FieldDefinition query

Tags: soql, tooling-api

I am able to retreive field definition for a custom object except last modified by. below is my SOQL.

```
select Label, DeveloperName , DataType, IsCalculated, RelationshipName 
from FieldDefinition 
where EntityDefinition.QualifiedApiName = 'objectname'
```

Comment: Your query works fine for me and includes the field `LastModifiedBy` for both standard and custom objects. Can you please add a more detailed description of how you are running this query and the issue you are seeing?

Answer (score 0):

To get the ID, use `LastModifiedById`:

```
select Label, DeveloperName , DataType, IsCalculated, RelationshipName, LastModifiedById
from FieldDefinition 
where EntityDefinition.QualifiedApiName = 'objectname'
```

You can also get other attributes defined by the [Name](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_name.htm) object:

```
select Label, DeveloperName , DataType, IsCalculated, RelationshipName, LastModifiedBy.Name, LastModifiedBy.Email
from FieldDefinition 
where EntityDefinition.QualifiedApiName = 'objectname'
```

Standard fields cannot generally be modified and will never have a Last Modified By.